# Javascript If statements

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

We are trying to print the people with birthdays (on the actual date) using javascript arrays to store the information.

We have three arrays, one to store the day, the month, and the person.

so here is what we have now:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!--
        Look Into Connectors
        28 JANUARY 2015
        Assignment 1

        Author: 
        Date: 
        This is the index/ homepage of the website. It is the main page that a user should land on.

        Filename: webpage
        supporting files: 
    -->
         <title>A Look Into IT</title>
    </head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is a website that offers free information on IT">
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var bmonth = ["4","4","4","4", "4", "4", "4"]
    var bday = ["8","6","27","22", "23", "23", "9"]
    var person = ["Jesse", "john","billy" , " Buddy Dyer", "John Morgan", "Will Smith", "Jonny"]
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
    for(i=0; i<=6; i++){
      if (month = bmonth[i]){
        if(day = bday[i]){
            document.write(person[i])

              }
       }else{
      document.write("There are no birthdays today")
}
    }
    //-->
    </script>





        </body>
    </html>
```

here is the output:
4/22/2015JessejohnbillBuddyDyerJohnMorganWillSmithjonny

it just prints all of the array information.

Comment: You really need to change the question title. This is not about if statements(the verb) but about why your code is not working as expected

Comment: Instead of hard-coding your `for` loop to stop at `6` you might want to account for adding more people/birthdates so your code is flexible. Maybe there's some property of an `array` that can, I dunno, `count` the # of items it contains so you could store it in a variable instead? ;) Also as others pointed out, look into assignment vs. equality: `=` vs `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 3):

instead of `if (month = bmonth[i])` and `if(day = bday[i])`
use `if (month == bmonth[i])` and `if(day == bday[i])`, respectively.

You may also want to use triple equals to `===`, but that another issue.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to add `break;` at the end of your `for` statement to stop it from counting

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using assignment operator `=` instead of the equality (sometimes called sameness) operator `==`

But you may still be left wondering why you got the output:

`JessejohnbillBuddyDyerJohnMorganWillSmithjonny`

The values of `month` and `day` will be evaluated for [truthyness](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) and all of the values in your arrays evaluate to true. This is why `document.write(person[i])` is printing all the names.

Also you really need to be using semicolons.